# Marketplaces and website SEO

Tags: seo, marketing

I would like to know if this is an issue for SEO if the description and the title of the product is the same on the marketplaces and on my site.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you own or manufacture the products? Or do these products belong to another company and you are acting as an affiliate?

Comment: No, but for majority I am the only one who selling it.

Answer (score 1):

This is duplication of content. Search engines will see the same content and will give priority to older content. Probably the one who first created and published unique content and is its author. If there are two bakeries in the street next to each other and the same product, then most likely that customers will continue to go to an older bakery. In online marketing, as in offline, commerce requires some sort of sweetie / zest, which distinguishes your business from the rest similar. Therefore, it is recommended to find a **Unique Point of Sale - UPS**.

Comment: The products was first on my website, I put later on marketplace, so my website should be first no?

Comment: In that case, what do you mean by the word marketplaces?

Comment: Sorry, I mean I created the website first (few months ago) and after I put my products on marketplace.

Comment: Use different descriptions on the two sites. Your website will likely service customers more familiar with your brand, so use more brand-building and introductory content on the marketplace and write content specifically pushing the product on your website.

Answer (score 1):

I would alter the title and the description and add some alternative content. Google will probably not rank 2 different pages if the title and description are exactly the same. Even if the content on the pages are different, if the title and description are identical this doesn't look that good on the search results.

It's important to put the keywords in the title and description that you want to rank for. So if you're selling "strawberry bubblegum" I would make sure that you have that keyword in both the title and description. But you should have some slight variation regarding the other words that you are using.